# How to redirect HTML index file to subfolder directory?

Tags: .htaccess, web, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

I have created a subfolder to access my HTML website. But the problem is, it is not running on the subdirectory URL but with the index.html aliases.

e.g. `https://example.com/my-html-site/index.html` (the website running the whole page).

But I want a simple redirection to run the website under the subdirectory like this below,

`https://example.com/my-html-site/`  (when I hit this URL then it shows a blank page).

Is there any way to redirect the https://example.com/my-html-site/index.html to https://example.com/my-html-site/ via htaccess file rules?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Based on your shown samples could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1/index.html [L]
```

Comment: Adding additional note here: JS/CS rewrite/redirect: You need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path . for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: @unimarck, could you please do let me know how it went? cheers.